# Vuejs method called twice

Tags: vuejs2

first of all I have to say that I'm new with VueJs but I have some troubles with lifecycle hooks understanding!

I have a component which has 3 tabs button and then three list which will be rendered conditionally:

```html
 <main class="wrapper">
    <div class="summary--tab pb">
      <span class="summary__tab--item " :class="{ active: isActive('cat1') }"
        >category 1</span
      >
      <span
        class="summary__tab--item"
        :class="{ active: isActive('cat2') }"
        @click.prevent="setActive('cat2')"
        >category 2</span
      >
      <span
        class="summary__tab--item"
        :class="{ active: isActive('cat3') }"
        @click.prevent="setActive('cat3')"
        >category 3</span
      >
    </div>
    <div class="projects_container">
      <template v-if="activeItem === 'cat1'">
        <div v-for="element in cat1Projects" :key="element.id" class="item">
          {{ element.title }}
          <br />
          {{ element.id }}
        </div>
      </template>
      <template v-else-if="activeItem === 'cat2'">
        <div v-for="element in cat2Projects" :key="element.id" class="item">
          {{ element.title }}
          <br />
          {{ element.id }}
        </div>
      </template>
      <template v-else>
        <div v-for="element in cat3Projects" :key="element.id" class="item">
          {{ element.title }}
          <br />
          {{ element.id }}
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </main>
```

and this is my methods:

```js
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      axios.get(this.baseUrl + 'projects.json').then(response => {
        this.projects = response.data.projects
      })
    },
    isActive(menuItem) {
      console.log('get', menuItem)
      return this.activeItem === menuItem
    },
    setActive(menuItem) {
      this.activeItem = menuItem
    }
  }
```

but I routed to this component I understood that isActive is calling both in beforeMount and beforeUpdate hooks.

here is my lifecycle hooks:

```js
  beforeCreate() {
    console.log('before created')
  },
  created() {
    console.log('created')
    this.fetchData()
  },
  beforeMount() {
    console.log('before mount')
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted')
  },
  beforeUpdate() {
    console.log('before update')
  },
  updated() {
    console.log('updated')
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    console.log('before destroy')
  },
  destroyed() {
    console.log('destroyed')
    this.$store.dispatch('closeMenu')
  }
```

how can I prevent this to happen?Or what is the better solution two handle this?

this is my console log:

```
created 

before mount 

get cat1 

get cat2 

get cat3 

mounted 

before update 

get cat1 

get cat2 

get cat3 

updated
```

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks for a diagram on the lifecycle flow. Also, can you include code calling the lifecycle methods such as your created() & mounted() ?

Comment: i read the documentation and some other refrences.but as i mentioned i'm new and didn't exactly found my problem.

I also edited my question.you can see my lifecycle methods.

Comment: It is probably because your fetchData method assigns value to this.projects and the cat1, cat2, cat3 depend on this.projects. Are you doing something like this? `this.cat1 = this.projects.cat1` ? because changing the value of this.cat1 would trigger the isActive method again

Comment: Get to know about [Vue.js lifecycle hooks workflow with real-time object comparison](https://blog.canopas.com/vue-3-lifecycle-hooks-with-real-time-example-1b772b89e085)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using `:class="{ active: isActive('cat#') }"` in your template.
You should try to avoid using functions in your template (outside of @handlers).

And the template is rendered twice, once when it is mounted, and once when it is updated.

If you want to avoid that, you can have a conditional in the template: `this.activeItem === 'cat1'`

If you find having the condition like `this.activeItem === 'cat1'` right in the template be a bit verbose, you can use the computed like this:

```js
computed:{
  activeItemKeyey() {
    return {
      cat1: this.activeItem === 'cat1',
      cat2: this.activeItem === 'cat2',
      cat3: this.activeItem === 'cat3',
    }
  }
}
```

and then in the template...

```html
    <div class="summary--tab pb">
      <span class="summary__tab--item " :class="{ active: activeItemKeyey['cat1'] }"
        >category 1</span
      >
      <span
        class="summary__tab--item"
        :class="{ active: activeItemKeyey['cat2'] }"
        @click.prevent="setActive('cat2')"
        >category 2</span
      >
      <span
        class="summary__tab--item"
        :class="{ active: activeItemKeyey['cat3'] }"
        @click.prevent="setActive('cat3')"
        >category 3</span
      >
    </div>
```

This might seem a bit of overkill, but if you structure your menu as an object (or array), it scales quite nicely.

Comment: by menu you mean my tabs buttons? fetch them from data object in a loop?

Comment: yes, it makes for a smaller template, and with less _surface area_ there's less room for bugs and code is easier to manage. And having _magic strings_ in the code is a good place for a typo to hide that the linter wouldn't find.